# How can I efficiently send data in a parallelized way to a REST endpoint using Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, okhttp

I have a huge file stored in HDFS, `mydata.txt`, where each line contains data that must be submitted to a REST endpoint. I am wondering how I can efficiently group/partition the data (the lines in the file) and then submit them to the REST endpoint using `OkHttp`. I want to group/partition the data because I don't want to create too many HTTP clients and also to distribute the workload.

For example, I have something like the following, currently.

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())
val client = new OkHttpClient
val input = "hdfs://myserver/path/to/mydata.txt"

sc.textFile(input)
 .foreach(line => {
  val request = new Request.Builder()
   .url("http://anotherserver/api/data")
   .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), line))
   .build()
  client.newCall(request).execute()
 })
```

As I understand, `foreach` is an `Action` so it is called on the driver program, thus, `client` does not have to be serialized and can be used on all the data (lines). Of course, this solution is not parallelized.

I thought about partitioning too, but I think the `foreachPartition` is also an `Action`.

```
sc.textFile(input)
 .map(line => (Random.nextInt(10), line))
 .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(10))
 .foreachPartition(iter => {
  while(iter.hasNext) {
   val item = iter.next()
   val line = item._2
   //submit to REST endpoint
  }
 })
```

Any thoughts on how to parallelize the work of submitting data to a REST endpoint using Spark?

*EDIT* It turns out that `OkHttpClient` is not serializable, and can't even be used inside the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach for solving these types of problems is as follows:

1. Ensure that the REST library you want to use is available to all executors. This eliminates the need to worry about serialization.
2. Choose the level of concurrency by the number of cores.
3. Repartition your data such that #partititions >= k * #executors. When accessing external services with variable throughput, I use a largish `k`, e.g., 5-10, to reduce the likelihood of a batch of "slow" inputs slowing the entire job.
4. `map()` the data and set up the client inside the body of the mapped function, which eliminates serialization problems. Return a pair of the input and success/failure as well as any diagnostic information.
5. Filter failures and decide what do with them, e.g., reprocess them (you could even keep a retry count).

If setting up the HTTP client is expensive, use `mapPartitions()` instead of `map()` as it would allow you to set up the client once and process many inputs with it.

The basic version:

```
def restCall(url: String): MyResultOrError = ...
val numCoresPerExecutor = ...
val numCores = numCoresPerExecutor * (sc.getExecutorStorageStatus.length - 1)
val result = rdd
  .repartition(5 * numCores)
  .map(url => (url, restCall(url)))
```

Comment: The `mapPartitions` approach worked for me. However, nothing happened unless I called an `action` like `collect` at the very end.

Comment: Of course, that's just how Spark works. Transformations simply build an execution DAG until an action is called.